# Running GO in IntelliJ IDEA CE 14 stopped working

Tags: go, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I was successfully able to install the go plugin (dev version 0.9.16), create my library and write some tests and examples and run them. Everything seemed cool. Something changed, I don't know what I did, and now whenever I try to run the module, I get an error=13, permission denied, cannot run program /.../go/src/mymodule in /.../go/src. Any ideas on how to fix this? I've googled the logical things and haven't found any help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest plugin release from [Github releases](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases), and things should work again.

Comment: I successfully installed the new plugin but now I get the error:   Error:go: can't load package: package .: no buildable Go source files in /Users/seth/Work/company/src/go

Comment: Please open an issue in the tracker, if you haven't done so already (please search for the issue before opening)